# How different are they, the derivative and the gradient both with regard to a vector?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

According to my research, let $\mathbf{x} = \bigg[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\bigg]^\top$,

$$\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} =
\bigg[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_2}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_n}\bigg]^\top$$

Whereas

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}) =
\bigg[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_2}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_n}\bigg]^\top$$

So they look like the same thing, but is it true? If they are different, which of the two equations above is wrong?

Comment: These are two different notations for the same thing.

Comment: In what kind of cases each expression is used then? Or are they the same in terms of use cases too?

Comment: The first quantity should be denoted as $\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,$ not $\,\frac{df}{dx}\;$

Comment: @greg Thanks, I modified it.